# In html what does a Aside (With a Heading) and Section (With a Heading) look like?

Tags: html

In html what does a Aside (With a Heading) and Section (With a Heading) code look like?

Which one of these are correct or are both of them wrong. When they say heading, do they mean an actual header like (h1,h2,h3) or the name of the header. Unsure how to write this? are my examples wrong?

```
<aside> 
<h1> </h1>
</aside>


<h1> aside </h1>

<section>
<h1> </h1>
</section>

<h1> section </h1>
```

Comment: You can test how it in different places like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp) or even here using a snippet. Also you can write it however you want as long as it gives your expected results. Or you can use a [tool](https://html5.validator.nu/) to check it your html page has a correct format.

Comment: As soon as w3schools presents itself as no longer useful, I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). 
For playing around in snippets you can use either the snippet-tool here on SO or something like [CodePen](https://codepen.io/). Hope you have a nice start into web-development.

Answer (score 0):

`<aside>`  : You can add content which are not necessarily directly related to the main content that surrounds it,but can provide additional information.

`<section>`:Generic section used to group different articles for different purposes or subjects, or to define the different sections of a single article. Generally used with a header.

This image might give you clear picture .

*These are related tags from stack overflow to your question.*

[image]

*This is how it looks like.*

[image]